# I got this error CS0103 and I don't know if this is from C# extension or if I forget to put something

Tags: c#, visual-studio-code

I don't know if this is an error with the C# extension or I just forgot something.

I was trying to make a health base system so I convert into a string to print the number then back to int, to its original form.

FYI this some of my code, not all of it another thing I know their other forms but it wasn't looking for.

[Example 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S1ZiT.png)

[example 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yYcvl.png)

```
class Conehead_Wizzard
{
    public string name;
    public string ConeHead_Powerful_spells;
    public int slots;
    public float Level_Up;
    public int Player_Health;
    public int Chance;
    public int b;
    public int c;


    public Conehead_Wizzard(string _name, string _ConeHead_Powerful_spells, 
        int _Player_Health)
    {
        name = _name;
        ConeHead_Powerful_spells = _ConeHead_Powerful_spells;
        slots = 5;
        Level_Up = 1.2f;
        Player_Health = 1000;
        b = 100;

        void Damage_Chance ()
        {
            Random Chance_ = new Random();
            int Chance = Chance_.Next(0, 100);

            if (Chance > 99)
            {
                System.Console.WriteLine(Player_Health - b);
                System.Console.WriteLine("you lost" + Player_Health + "of your health");
                Player_Health--;
                string a = Convert.ToString(Player_Health);
            }
            else
            {
                System.Console.WriteLine("Miss!, next player");
                c = Convert.ToInt16(Player_Health);
            }
        }
    }
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Conehead_Wizzard wizzard = new Conehead_Wizzard("Cone_Head ", 
            "The Cone of time &" + " Cone of shield", Player_Health);
    }
}
```

Comment: Please post error messages and code as text, not images.

Comment: In your "new Conehead_Wizzard", the parameter "_Player_Health" needs to be set to a value before the value of "Player_Health" in the Conehead_Wizzard class could have a value. With your current code you would be best passing in a numeric value. FYI, "Player_Health" cannot be used here, because you don't yet have an instance of the Conehead_Wizard class - if you did, you'd certainly be able to set the new wizard's player health to the same as an existing wizard.

Comment: @MarkRabjohn thank you for the insight

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You haven't declared the variable `Player_Health` in the `Main` method. Did you maybe intend to do something as follows:

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        int Player_Health = 1000;
        Conehead_Wizzard wizzard = new Conehead_Wizzard("Cone_Head ", "The Cone of time &" + " Cone of shield", Player_Health);

    }
```

Although this should allow you to compile, be aware, the constructor isn't using the value passed into `_Player_Health`. It just sets `wizzard.Player_Health` to 1000. If you want to use it, you need to change your constructor to something like this:

```
    public Conehead_Wizzard(string _name, string _ConeHead_Powerful_spells, int _Player_Health)
    {
        name = _name;
        ConeHead_Powerful_spells = _ConeHead_Powerful_spells;
        slots = 5;
        Level_Up = 1.2f;

        Player_Health = _Player_Health;

        b = 100;
    }
```

Comment: THANK You,  VanMeterMichael

Comment: @Fire-Source: If that answered your question, would you kindly mark it as the accepted answer? Thanks!